# Identify how server routs external connection into local 10.1.0.* address

Tags: linux, networking, apache-http-server

I inherited a server (long story), let's call it Server A. The function I am trying to understand is as follows:
Programmed external computer devices, wherever they may be in the world, as soon as they are connected to internet, automatically connect to Server A and present an html interface, accessible via the 10.1.*.* addresses on Server A's local network.

Where can I find the relevant files that make this possible? A brief look at `/etc/apache2` in Server A shows some related configuration, but no silver bullet. OpenVPN is also installed on the system.

System specs: Ubuntu from around 2010, Linux kernel 2.6.28-19-server, Apache 2.2.11

Answer (score 3):

This computer is most likely an OpenVPN server, as well as an Apache
web server.

The clients create a secure VPN to this server and then open the initial
web page, once the server becomes accessible via the VPN.

The IP address of `10.1.*.*` is typical for the secure network that is
created by the VPN client, appearing on the client computer as
a virtual network adapter.

You will need to learn both OpenVPN and Apache and examine their
configuration files, to better understand this setup.